Growth polynomial of the Associahedron graph ? (Is it approximately Gaussian ?)
Consider  Associahedron, consider graph build from its vertices and edges. Choose some vertex. Let us count the number of vertices on distances $k$ from the selected vertex. Write a generating polynomial $g(t) = \sum_k g_k tˆk$.
Question 1: What is  known about $g(t)$ ?
Consider $n$ to be quite large.
Question 2: Is it true that coefficients $g_k$ are well approximated by the Gaussian ? (It might be natural to expect such phenomena for any symmetric polytopes).
See also: What are compact manifolds such that GROWTH (of spheres volumes) is well approximated by the Gaussian normal distribution?
More on graphs <-> polytopes correspondence  examples in beautiful post in Gil Kalai's blog: https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/ziegler%C2%B4s-lecture-on-the-associahedron/
See also: What Cayley graphs arise as nodes+edges from "nice" polytopes and when are these polytopes convex?

A few quick comments. Of course, everything you ask about depends on the order $n$ of the associahedron in question, although you mostly suppress this dependence in your notation. Also, the associahedron is not vertex transitive, so your generating function depends also on which vertex you choose as the base. Nevertheless, there is a natural choice of base vertex, the minimum of the Tamari lattice, and indeed your question essentially asks about the rank generating function of the Tamari lattice (although the Tamari lattice is not graded, so we have to interpret this correctly.)

@SamHopkins Thanks for the comment ! Welcome to extend it. Yes, surely depends. Is something is known for any choice ? Gaussian approximation I think should not depend on any choice like that.

@SamHopkins "the natural choice of base" is it something like (((((ab)c)d)e) - I mean the brackets are placed in the most simple way ?

I guess it is true - from that picture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamari_lattice

https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.10986
Refined product formulas for Tamari intervals
Alin Bostan, Frédéric Chyzak, Vincent Pilaud
We provide short product formulas for the f-vectors of the canonical complexes of the Tamari lattices and of the cellular diagonals of the associahedra.

Let's consider the associahedron whose vertices are triangulations of an $n$-gon. Sleator, Tarjan, and Thurston (Rotation distance, triangulations, and hyperbolic geometry, JAMS, 1988)
give a simple argument that the maximum distance between two triangulations is at most $2n-10$. Namely, if you pick a boundary vertex $v$, it's always possible to do a flip which increases its degree, unless you are already at the triangulation which has all its diagonals incident to $v$. So, if $T$ and $T'$ are two triangulations, you can get from $T$ to $T'$ via the triangulation with all diagonals incident to $v$ in at most $2n-6 - \textrm{deg}_T(v) - \textrm{deg}_{T'}(v)$ steps, where the degrees are with respect to the diagonals only. They then give a simple averaging argument that if $n$ is at least 12, $v$ can be chosen so the sum of the degrees of $v$ in $T$ and $T'$ is at least 4.
If we construct the generating polynomial starting from the bottom of the Tamari lattice, $T_0$, (where all the edges are incident to vertex $0$) as suggested by Sam, the maximum distance will be much less: by the same argument, we can always increase the degree of 0 by one at each step, and obviously we can't increase it by more than one. So the distance of $T$ from $T_0$ is just $n-3-\deg_T(0)$.
The count of triangulations by degree of a fixed vertex is known to be given by ballot numbers. (See A009766 of the OEIS.) The formula for those at distance $k$ is $\frac{n-2-k}{n-2}\binom{n-3+k}{n-3}$. This is very far from being approximately Gaussian.
If we start from a more typical vertex of the associahedron, though, the results might look more like what the OP proposed.
Edited to add: Sleator, Tarjan, and Thurston actually showed (using hyperbolic geometry) that for $n$ sufficiently large, the bound they found is tight. Their proof gave no indication of how big $n$ had to be, and for small values of $n$ (but at least 12), their bound was computed to be sharp. Finally their bound was shown to be sharp for all $n$ at least 12 by Pournin, https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6296. This shows that there are some vertices of the associahedron for which the behaviour will be quite different from the one I discussed above.

Thanks a lot for sharing !
